# Using predict() in R knowing some, but not all, predictor values in newdata argument

Tags: r, r-caret, predict, rpart

I am fitting a model using the `caret` package in R using training data with 100+ predictor variables. I then try to use the model to predict an outcome but only based on some predictor values (I do not know the rest). Is it even possible to predict in such a situation?

Essentially I am running this code:

```
predict(<MODEL>, newdata = data.frame(<X1> = <x1>, <X2> = <x2>, <X3> = <x3>))
```

However there are `<X100+>`, as mentioned. As expected, R gives me the following error `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '<X4>' not found`.

Is it possible to somehow set a 'baseline' level for the other predictors?

If nothing works, I am thinking of just substituting the mean of the predictors from my data for the respective missing predictors. Is this a valid approach? Should I use the train or test data to find these mean values?

(I have not provided data as I don't think it's necessary. If needed I can provide it. I have fitted the model in `caret` using `train(..., method = "rpart", ...)`.)

Comment: substituting the mean of the predictor (either training or testing) for missing values is not ridiculous.

Comment: If you had standardized variables, centered by the mean, you might be able to set them all = 0, which would be the mean.

Comment: That's a good point @Dylan_Gomes. I'm just wondering what to do for categorical variables. I'm thinking of taking the mode.

Comment: I guess if you don't have an interaction term between the categorical and the predictor of interest, it might not make a big difference for the response ~ predictorA relationship? It will move your predicted response up and down, but the relationship should hold I think.. I guess it depends on what you want to do with it / what you are interested in

Comment: That's true. It is kind of a case-by-case problem at the moment, relative to the specific data. Thanks for the suggestions!